# how to capture only digits in array using if statement in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

```
len=${#newarray[*]}

for ((i=0;i<${len};i++)); do

    if [[ "${newarray[$i]}" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then 

        echo "${newarray[$i]}"     
    fi
```

this is my code I need to get only digits from the array list and their count as well. but there is an issue that shows alphabetical values only.

given getdata.txtcontains -

```
   cat  
   dog
   1234
   pl345
   567ab
   12234
```

Comment: Your `if/else` is backwards. You should do the `echo` in the `if` and `continue` in the `else`, since `if` matches numeric values.

Comment: Why are you echoing `newfolders` instead of `value`?

Comment: You can simply use `len` in `for ((i=0;i<len;i++)); do` (variables are automatically expanded within `(( ... ))`)

Comment: yes i changed the if-else but it captures pl345 as well @Barmar

Comment: thank you i did it that way my problem with the if else stement @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Also, you are not wrong, but you do not need to quote within `[[ ... ]]` -- you do in all other cases -- so you are safe if you always quote, just be aware of the distinction.

Comment: i put newfolder accidently while posting the code its not the matter is code picks 
 pl345 as well for ((i=0;i<$len;i++)); do

    if [[ "${newfolders[$i]}" =~ [[:digit:]] ]]; then 

        echo "${newfolders[$i]}"  @Barmar

Comment: If you don't anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`, it looks for a digit anywhere in it, not the whole thing.

Comment: if [[ "${newfolders[$i]}" =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]; gave it this way nothing shows @Barmar

Comment: That only matches 1 digit. You need + to match at least 1 digit.

Comment: The regexp in the question is correct, the only problem was the `if/else`.

Comment: Why not simply `digits=$(tr -cd 0-9 <<<"$input")`?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the desired output? There are different interpretations of your question.

Comment: for ((i=0;i<$len;i++)); do

    if [[ "${value[$i]}" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then 

        echo "${value[$i]}"
           
    else
         continue  
    fi
done    @Barmar

Comment: I tested the code in my answer, it works.

Comment: There's no need for `else continue`, since there's nothing else in the loop to skip over.

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Edit the question to show the problem.

Comment: edited  the code@Barmar

Answer (score 3):

Having:

```
value=(cat dog 1234 pl345 567ab 12234)
```

You could print "only numbers":

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${value[@]}" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
1234
345
567
12234
```

or maybe you want "only lines that contain only numbers":

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${value[@]}" | grep -x "[0-9]*"
1234
12234
```

or maybe you want "only lines with a number":

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${value[@]}" | grep "[0-9]"
1234
pl345
567ab
12234
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if/else` is backwards.

```
value=(cat dog 1234 pl345 567ab 12234)
len=${#value[*]}
    
for ((i=0;i<${len};i++)); do
    if [[ "${value[$i]}" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then 
         echo "${value[$i]}"   
    fi
done
```

This outputs:

```
1234
12234
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-regex way of doing it in `bash` using `shopt`:

```
# enable extended glob
shopt -s extglob

value=(cat dog 1234 pl345 567ab 12234)

# lop through array and print only it contains 1+ digits
for v in "${value[@]}"; do [[ $v == +([0-9]) ]] && echo "$v"; done
```

```
1234
12234
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use two nested loops:

1. iterate over all elements of an array
2. iterate over all chars in the element, check if the char is a digit

(2) would probably be simpler with grep, but since we're speaking of bash implementaton I've came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=(cat dog 1234 pl345 567ab 12234) # input array

for s in "${a[@]}"; do # iterate over all elements of our array
        res=''
        for ((i=0;i<${#s};i++)); do # iterate over all chars of element $s
                c="${s:$i:1}" # $c is now char at $i position inside $s
                case "$c" in
                        [0-9]) res="${res}${c}" # append digit to res
                esac
        done
        [ -n "$res" ] && echo "$res" # if $s contains at least 1 digit, print it
                                     # you may add $res to another array here if needed

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```sh
tr -dc '0-9\n' <getdata.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ cat getdata.txt |grep -P '^[0-9]+$'
```